# crystal reports 9... formula not working

Tags: crystal-reports

I have written this formula in crystl reports 9

and I am not getting the result.. if anybody could help?

```
if ({myfield.field1} = "0")  and (Mid({myfield.field2},1,1) = "2") then
        formula = "abc"
elseif ({myfield.field1} = "0") and (Mid({myfield.field2},1,1) = "1") then
        formula = "def"
end if
```

Comment: is there any error message? Where did you declare `formula`

Comment: there is no error message.. i have declared the formula in a section of my rpt

Comment: it just doesn't get printed...

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons your formula isn't returning anything:

1. The `if` and `elseif` statements can never evaluate to true. If `{myField.field}="0"` then `mid({myField.field},1,1)` will always equal "0".
2. You don't have an `else` clause to capture all other cases, so your formula will always be null.

Comment: @Ryan... Thanks for your input.. Deleting the answer as it is no more required.

Comment: sorry for the stupidity but both the fields are different             if ({myfield.field1} = "0")  and (Mid({myfield.field2},1,1) = "2")

Comment: @user2636787 I would you suggest you place field1, field2, and this formula in your details section for troubleshooting. My guess is that your field1 and field2 just don't contain the values that you're assuming they do. You could also add an else-clause to test with.